How do I start my node server when deploying to AWS via Bitbucket pipeline?
I'm using a Bitbucket pipeline to deploy my Node application to an EC2 instance running linux. I created a script to start my application:
# Source nvm and load Node.js environment for root user
export NVM_DIR="/home/ec2-user/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# Navigate to the API directory
cd /api

# Start the node server
npm start

I'm calling that script from my AppSpec.yml as follows:
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
      - location: deploy/nodestart.sh
        timeout: 30
        runas: root

The pipeline execution fails. Via the AWS Console I can see that the start of the application actually succeeded, but the start of the Node server is a blocking event. The script hangs and then it exceeds the timeout, is terminated and then the deployment fails.
How do I start Node asynchronously to the deployment so that the deployment terminates cleanly? Thanks for your advice!


Maybe try npm start &. This will run npm as a background process and allow your script to exit. This is just a guess, though, based on my knowledge of Linux. There is likely a better way to run a node server.

Also, you should probably start your application in the ApplicationStart hook of AppSpec.yml instead of AfterInstall. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html for details.

Ultimately, I set this to run as a service, with a lcapi.service definition file inside of /etc/systemd/system.
I copy this in as part of the pipeline deployment. These commands enable the service, reload the new service definition for the OS, and then start the service.
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/lcapi.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start lcapi.service

to see the status of your running service:
systemctl status lcapi.service

For more information on setting up linux services, see: https://natancabral.medium.com/run-node-js-service-with-systemd-on-linux-42cfdf0ad7b2
